# Is it really impossible for a hypnotist to make a participant do something against their will?

Tags: hypnosis

Is there any evidence of a hypnotist making someone do something against their will while in a hypnotic state?

I know there are many sites by practicioners that state it is impossible, but they have a vested interest in making their potential patients feel safe.

Comment: I deleted the part about regret, because it is a banal truth that people regret what they do without being hypnotized.

Comment: Short answer: no. People under hypnoses are very aware of what's going on and are still in control of what they are doing,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question cannot be answered empirically.

> Thus, a refusal to carry out antisocial actions can be ascribed to insufficient depth of hypnosis (or inadequate hypnotic technique), while the behavior of S[ubject]s who comply can be explained by asserting that the action merely represents what they would have done anyway. (Orne, 1972)

---

Sources:

- Orne, M. T. (1972). Can a hypnotized subject be compelled to carry out otherwise unacceptable behavior? A discussion. *International Journal of Clinical and Experimental Hypnosis, 20*(2), 101-117.

Comment: Link to article http://www.psych.upenn.edu/history/orne/orneijceh19722101117.html

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @what's great answer (that this is not a testable question), a while ago I watched a [Derren Brown episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90xfZJQzAhc) where he successfully hypnotizes someone to assassinate a co-conspirator.

This was supposedly to test the [Manchurian Candidate hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_F._Kennedy_assassination_conspiracy_theories#Manchurian_candidate_hypothesis) (and incorporating a polka-dot dress) - a conspiracy theory that the CIA used hypnosis to train unsuspecting victims to assassinate on command.